# Flutter: keyboard disappears immediately when editing my text fields it closes as soon as i try to write

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling

i have tried everything but it is not working. when i try to write in the text field it closes automatically and the screen refreshes itself. same happening to my signup screen. i cannot type anything. i have tried everything from removing MediaQuery size presence from my code and many more things.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:magnet/common/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:magnet/constants.dart';
import 'package:magnet/providers/login_provider.dart';
import 'package:magnet/screens/phoneloginscreen.dart';
import 'package:magnet/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../components/square_tile.dart';
import '../models/user.dart';
import '../resources/auth_methods.dart';
import '../responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import '../responsive/responsive_layout.dart';
import '../responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import '../utils/colors.dart';
import '../utils/global_variable.dart';
import '../utils/utils.dart';
import '../widgets/text_field_input.dart';
import '../providers/login_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _obscureText = true;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
  }

  void loginUser() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String res = await AuthMethods().loginUser(
        email: _emailController.text, password: _passwordController.text);
    if (res == 'success') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ResponsiveLayout(
              mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
              webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
            ),
          ),
              (route) => false);

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      showSnackBar(context, res);
    }
  }

  Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async {
    if (email.trim().isEmpty) {
      showSnackBar(context, "Please enter your email address");
      return;
    }
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
      showSnackBar(context, "Password reset link has been sent to your email");
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message ?? "An error occurred");
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor, // Set a background color
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0, // Removes the shadow from the app bar
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Login",
          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: primaryColor),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Lottie.asset('assets/login3.json', height: 180), // Updated animation asset name
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                TextFieldInput(
                  hintText: 'Enter your email',
                  textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  textEditingController: _emailController,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, // For better UX
                ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 24,
                  ),
                  TextFieldInput(
                    hintText: 'Enter your password',
                    textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                    textEditingController: _passwordController,
                    isPass: true,
                    obscureText: _obscureText,
                    suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        setState(() {
                          _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        _obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off, color: Colors.white,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        resetPassword(_emailController.text);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot Password?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: blueColor, // Background color
                      onPrimary: Colors.white, // Text color
                      minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50), // Button size
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: _isLoading ? null : loginUser, // Disable button when loading
                    child: _isLoading
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                        : Text('Log in'),
                  ),
                  // Flexible(
                  //   child: Container(),
                  //   flex: 2,
                  // ),
                  // Row(
                  //   children: [
                  //     Expanded(child: Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade600,)),
                  //     SizedBox(width: 5,),
                  //     Text("OR", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                  //     SizedBox(width: 5,),
                  //     Expanded(child: Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade600,))
                  //   ],
                  // ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  // Padding(
                  //   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  //   child: Text("Sign up with Google or Apple",),
                  // ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  // Row(
                  //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  //   children: [
                  //     // google button
                  //     SquareTile(
                  //       imagePath: 'assets/google.png', onTap: () { AuthMethods().signInWithGoogle(); },
                  //     ),
                  //
                  //     SizedBox(width: 25),
                  //
                  //     // apple button
                  //     SquareTile(
                  //         onTap: () {},
                  //         imagePath: 'assets/apple.png'
                  //     )
                  //   ],
                  // ),
                  // CustomButton(text: "Continue With Phone Number", onPressed: (){
                  //   Navigator.push(
                  //     context,
                  //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhoneLoginScreen2()),
                  //   );
                  // }),
                  SizedBox(height: 120),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Don't have an account?",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const SignupScreen(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: blueColor, // Button text color
                          ),
                          child: Text('Sign up'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the problem comes from the custom `TextFieldInput` widget. How is it implemented? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see the `TextFieldInput` widget class, but I suspect you may have a key for the field which is not initialized outside of the build method.

Example:

```
TextFormField(
  key: GlobalKey<FormFieldState>(), // This key should be moved
),
```

Try initializing the key outside of the build method. I'm not sure as to why this happens, I'd have to dig to find out.